# Basic rectangle splitting

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

*I'm stuck on some trivial question and, well, I guess I need help here.*

[image]

I have two rectangles and it's guaranteed that they have one common point from their 4 base points **(upper part of the picture).** It's also guaranteed that they are axis-aligned.

*I know this common point (which also can be easily deduced), dimensions and the coordinates of these rectangles.*

---

Now, I need to *retrieve the coordinates* of the rectangles named `1` and `2` and I'm seeking for an easy way to do that **(lower part of the picture)**.

*My current implementation relies on many `if` statements and I suspect I'm too stupid to find a better way.*

Thank you.

#### Update: My current implementation.

```
Point commonPoint = getCommonPoint(bigRectangle, smallRectangle);

rectangle2 = new Rectangle(smallRectangle.getAdjacentVerticalPoint(commonPoint),
                           bigRectangle.getOppositePoint(commonPoint));

rectangle1 = new Rectangle(smallRectangle.getAdjacentHorizontalPoint(commonPoint)
                           bigRectangle.getOppositePoint(commonPoint));

// Now simply adjust one of these rectangles to remove the overlap,
// it's trivial - we take the 'opposite' points for 'small' and 'big'
// rectangles and then use their absolute coordinate difference as
// a fix for either width of 'rectangle2' or height of 'rectangle1'
// (in this situation it's going to be width).

adjustRectangle(rectangle2);
```

This is refactored, but still methods `getCommonPoint` and `getAdjacent...` and `getOpposite` have many `if` statements and I thought if this can be done better.

Comment: Er, which language are you using, surely you can't be using C#, java *and* c++?  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: voting to close -- too broad a question, too many programming language tags. Who knows what language he means or if language is important at all.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens I wrote separate if statements to determine if my case falls for 4 possible cases and then used separate parts of code to determine the coordinates of the rectangles. However, I suspect, this can be done smart and without even determining the 1 of 4 possible states.

Comment: it is stupid to downvote this question or vote for close .

Comment: @Shahzeb: It's not too bright to ask a question and say that its key concepts include C#, Java, C++, and lord knows what else. That satisfies the "unclear" criteria for a down-vote. Also he shows no code.

Comment: Can you post the code you have right now?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels To be honest, posting your questions under a tag like `language-agnostic` wouldn't probably lead to solving the problem. I'm assured that most of the developers who are using stackoverflow have filters for their favorite languages and I'm also sure that probably a vast part of them could help me with this trivial question. So why not put all those `C#`, `Java` and `C++` tags here? Especially, when the solution to this "problem" can easily be written using any of them in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Yippie-Kai-Yay: It's a mis-use of tags as the question truly is language agnostic. If you mis-use the tags, expect a possible backlash. The tags aren't just for your benefit, and in fact far from it. They're mainly for folks searching this site months from now with a similar question. Adding misleading tags will just muddy their searches. Better, if you don't get a decent answer within 48 hours, put a bounty on your question if it is important.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay, this definitely makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top and bottom values of Rectangle 1 are the same as the big rectangle. The left and right values of rectangle 2 are the same as the small rectangle. We only need to obtain the left and right values of rectangle 1, and the top and bottom values for rectangle 2. So we only have 2 simple if-statements:

```
if (bigRectangle.Left == smallRectangle.Left) 
    left = smallRectangle.Right
    right = bigRectangle.Right
else
    left = bigRectangle.Left
    right = smallRectangle.Left
rectangle1 = new Rectangle(left, bigRectangle.Top, right - left, bigRectangle.Height)

if (bigRectangle.Top == smallRectangle.Top)
    top = smallRectangle.Bottom
    bottom = bigRectangle.Bottom
else
    top = bigRectangle.Top
    bottom = smallRectangle.Top
rectangle2 = new Rectangle(smallRectangle.Left, top, smallRectangle.Width, bottom - top)
```

In the above, the `Rectangle` constructors takes as inputs: left, top, width, height.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, seems like you need to have an if (or switch) statement to determine the orientation of the rectangle, and from there it would just be some easy adding and subtracting:

If you know the coords of the inner blue rectangle (and the dimensions of the rect as a whole), then finding the others should be no problem. One of the R1 and R2 points will always be the same: equal to the adjacent blue rect point. and the others is just a lil math.

Doesn't seem like you can get away from the initial if/switch statement. If the rectangle could only be up or down, then you could just make the offset negative or positive, but it can also be left or right..so you might be stuck there. You can make a -/+ offset for a vertical or horizontal state,but then you'd have to do a check on each calculation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had `RA` and `RB` as your inputs, and whatever language you're using has a `Rectangle` class, here's a way to do it with 4 `if`s, `Math.Min`, `Math.Max`, and `Math.Abs`:

```
Rectangle r1, r2; // Note - Rectangle constructor: new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height)
if (RA.X = RB.X) {  
    r1 = new Rectangle(Math.Min(RA.Right, RB.Right), Math.Min(RA.Y, RB.Y), Math.Abs(RA.Width - RB.Width), Math.Max(RA.Height, RB.Height));  
    if (RA.Y = RB.Y) {
        // Intersects Top Left
        r2 = new Rectangle(RA.X, Math.Min(RA.Bottom, RB.Bottom), Math.Min(RA.Width, RB.Width), Math.Abs(RA.Height - RB.Height));  
    } else {  
        // Intersects Bottom Left
        r2 = new Rectangle(RA.X, Math.Max(RA.Bottom, RB.Bottom), Math.Min(RA.Width, RB.Width), Math.Abs(RA.Height - RB.Height));
    }  
} else {  
    r1 = new Rectangle(Math.Min(RA.X, RB.X), Math.Min(RA.Y, RB.Y), Math.Abs(RA.Width - RB.Width), Math.Max(RA.Height, RB.Height));
    if (RA.Y = RB.Y) {  
        // Intersects Top Right
        r2 = new Rectangle(Math.Max(RA.X, RB.X), Math.Min(RA.Bottom, RB.Bottom), Math.Min(RA.Width, RB.Width), Math.Abs(RA.Height - RB.Height));
    } else {  
        // Intersects Bottom Right
        r2 = new Rectangle(Math.Max(RA.X, RB.X), Math.Min(RA.X, RA.Y), Math.Min(RA.Width, RB.Width), Math.Abs(RA.Height - RB.Height));
    }  
}
```

This code was written in Notepad so it might have a typo or two, but the logic is sound.